# Java type implementation of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm

So I have a recursive function as follow;

```
Sq(1) = 1
Sq(n) = Sq(n-1) + 2*n - 1 for n > 1
```

and I know that;

```
sq(n)=n²
```

satisfies the conditions, since

```
n²=(n−1)²+2n−1
```

and

```
1²=1
```

To prove that this is the only possible solution, we can use induction. Assume `sq(n−1)=(n−1)²`. Then we get:

```
sq(n)=(n−1)²+2n−1=n².
```

I need a way of implementing this into a java algorithm. Could anyone do this? Or well constructed psuedo-code is acceptable.

Comment: I assume you mean "implementing Sq" and not sq or your proof.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems homework I will not go into much detail:

```
int sq(int n) 
    if n == 1 then return 1   //This will break the recursion

    return sq(n - 1) + (2*n - 1)  //recursive call
```

You can find some examples as to resolving some problems through recursion [here](http://www.toves.org/books/java/ch18-recurex/).